# Difference between dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given two Data Frames D1 and D2 representing two tables in SQL with same columns and same primary key. What is the best way to find difference between the both?

Difference Includes:
1. All records in D1 not in D2
2. All records in D2 not in D1
3. Any updated records in D1 compare to D2.

Comment: I would do a full-outer-join

Answer (score 1):

make use of left_semi,left_anti join on DataFrame.

i.e:

```
df1.join(df2,joinExpr,"left_semi")(or)df1.join(df2,joinExpr,"left_anti")
```